# Properness of the blow ups of arithmetic schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

In Silverman's textbook Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, on page 345, he defined the blow up of an arithmetic surface (or a two dimensional scheme) at the point $(\pi,x,y) = (0,0,0)$ (i.e. reducing modulo $\pi$ since we are interested in what happens on the special fiber).

I believe we can extend his definition directly to blowing up subschemes e.g., say if we want to blow-up the whole $x$-axis instead, then we only consider the generators $\pi$ and $y$ for the subscheme? Also, his definition should not be limited to only arithmetic surfaces (we just add more variables and charts)?

Now let us fix an arithmetic scheme $C$ over a local ring $\mathcal{O}$ with uniformizer $\pi$. Following Silverman's definition, I suppose blowing up $C$ at any arithmetic subschemes (which we include the additional generator $\pi$ so that the generic fiber remains unaffected) gives us a new model $C^{\prime}$, together with a blow up map $C^{\prime} \rightarrow C$. My main question being, if $C$ is proper then is $C^{\prime}$ also proper? i.e. is the morphism $C^{\prime} \rightarrow \text{Spec}(\mathcal{O})$ a proper morphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all of what you ask is true. Let $X$ be a scheme, and let $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{O}_X$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals with corresponding closed subscheme $Z$. Then the blowup of $X$ along $Z$ is $$Bl_Z X := \underline{\operatorname{Proj}}_X \bigoplus_{n\geq 0} \mathcal{I}^n,$$ equipped with the natural projection $Bl_ZX\to X$. Being a relative proj, this morphism is automatically proper. In particular, writing $C'\to \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}$ as $C'\to C\to\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}$ and observing the composition of proper morphisms is proper, we see that $C'\to \operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}$ is indeed proper.

For more material about this definition of the blowup along a subscheme, you may consult Hartshorne chapter II section 7, Vakil chapter 22, or [tag 01OF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OF) at the Stacks Project.

---

To see that this recovers the "classical" construction of the blowup, we work affine locally on $X$ and so we may take $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$. Then we may work with $I=\mathcal{I}(X)$ (the global sections of the sheaf of ideals) and the usual proj instead of the relative proj. Then $\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} I^n\cong A[tI]$ where $t$ is in degree 1 ($t$ is a formal variable to keep track of the grading). Choosing generators $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ for $I$, we can re-express $A[tI]$ as $A[y_1,\cdots,y_n]/(f_iy_j-f_jy_i)$ with the $f_i\in A$ and the $y_i$ in degree one (representing $tf_i$). But the Proj of this algebra is exactly the classical construction of the blowup: it's $V((f_iy_j-f_jy_i)_{i,j})\subset X\times\Bbb P^{n-1}$ where the $y_i$ are coordinates on $\Bbb P^{n-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one additional question if you are willing to answer again: how can we see that the blow-up construction given by equations (e.g. Silverman's construction) is equivalent to the more general $\textbf{Proj}$ construction along a closed subscheme?

Comment: Compute in coordinates. Affine-locally on $X$, the graded algebra $\bigoplus_{n\geq0} \mathcal{I}^n$ is the same as what you would take Proj of to get the description that Silverman gives. (Try looking at the blowup of the origin in $\Bbb A^2$ for a specific example.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \mathcal{I}^n$ is the same as what Silverman gave? For example, I believe blowing up $\mathbb{A}^2$ at the origin gives the variety $V(xu - yt)$ in $\mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ where $x,y$ are the affine coordiantes of $\mathbb{A}^2$ and $u,t$ are the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^1$. (This variety is obtained by taking a $\text{Proj}$?) What would $\mathcal{I}$ and $\bigoplus_{n \ge 0} \mathcal{I}^n$ be in this case?

Comment: @YKASK I've added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I just have a few more questions regarding your newest answer: I assume you are using the map $k[X][y_1,...,y_n] \rightarrow k[X][f_1t,...,f_nt]$ where $y_i \mapsto f_it$ to claim that $k[X][y_1,...,y_n]/(f_iy_j - f_jy_i) \cong k[X][tI]$? So is it true that the kernel of this map should be $(f_iy_j - f_jy_i)$? I see that the kernel is $(y_i - f_it) \cap k[X][y_1,...,y_n]$ but not immediately see how it equals to $(f_iy_j - f_jy_i)$. Another question being, can I just replace $k$ with $\mathcal{O}$ and everything stays the same where $\mathcal{O}$ is a local ring?

Comment: I've clarified a little - really, $X$ can be any scheme and then we work affine locally, so we can assume $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$. To check that the kernel is as claimed should be a relatively straightforward exercise in elimination theory - I think you ought to be able to do it yourself, and if you get stuck, perhaps you may consider posting a new question.

Comment: I will try to figure out the kernel part myself. Thanks for all the help!