# Equivalence of definitions of blowup of $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field. I want to show that these two schemes are isomorphic:

the closed subscheme of $Spec(k[x,y]) \times_k Proj(k[u, v])$ given by $xv = yu$.

and $\underline{Proj}_{X}(O_X \oplus I \oplus I^2 \oplus ...)$ , where $X = \mathbb{A}^2_k, I = (x, y) \subseteq k[x,y]$ = $Proj(k[x, y] [It])$, where $k[x, y] [It]$ is the Rees algebra.

I tried covering them with affine open subsets, and found that the first scheme is covered by $D(u) = Spec(k[x, y, w ] / (xw - y))$  (setting $w = v/u$) and $D(v) = Spec(k[x,y, t] /( x - yt))$ (setting $t= u/v)$

When I try the same thing with the Proj, I get $D(xt) = Spec(k[x, y][It]_{xt : 0})$ and $D(yt) = Spec(k[x, y][It]_{yt : 0})$.

I can't get them to match. The problem is that the Rees algebra is a subring of the polynomial ring, and not a quotient.

I then tried taking the inclusion $k[x, y][It]$ into $k[x, y, t]$, and seeing if the induced map $U \subseteq Proj(k[x_0, y_0, t]) \rightarrow Proj(k[x, y][It])$ is useful (the $x_0$ and $y_0$ are to indicate that they have degree 0). But $Proj(k[x_0, y_0, t])$ is just $Spec(k[x, y])$ so it turned out not to be.

Comment: You could try to construct a graded isomorphism $k[x,y][u,v] / (xv-yu) \cong k[x,y][It]$.

Comment: Does the second half of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505681/properness-of-the-blow-ups-of-arithmetic-schemes-by-silverman/4505699#4505699) solve your question?